# Infragistics XamSyntaxEditor - Syntax parsing EBNF for xml

Tags: c#, xml, infragistics, ebnf

I am trying to create a CustomLanguage for xml in order to get syntax highlighting in xamSyntaxEditor for xml.

I have looked at "[How to use infragistics syntax parsing engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253098/how-to-use-infragistics-syntax-parsing-engine)" and thought a good way to start would be to get the EBNF file for XML and use the  Infragistics.Documents.Parsing.Grammar.LoadEbnd() Method.

I used the EBNF file from http://www.jelks.nu/XML/xmlebnf.txt

This proved to be too easy. I got a lot of Errors.
Starting with a "UnrecognizedContent" Error for "::".

My little knowledge told me that "::=" is an important part of EBNF.

What did I do wrong? Does this even use regular EBNF?

Comment: Is there a good reason that you're reimplementing an XML parser from scratch rather than using one of the XML parsers available off-the-shelf? The whole point of XML is that it's shared syntax for many languages, and that the application only needs to deal with the semantics... If you really do want to do this for some reason, I'd suggest looking at the authoritative grammar in the XML Recommendation itself rather than trusting a second-source.

Answer (score 1):

In the sample's browser for WPF 13.2, under Syntax Parsing Engine > Data, there is a sample named CustomLanguage. This sample shows a custom XML grammar being used to highlight syntax. The grammar itself can be found in the samples source code folder at the following relative path:
\CLR4.0\IGSyntaxParsingEngine\Samples\Languages\XML.ebnf